# Make page element remain visible after reload/refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a control button wrapped in a div on my form. If the user clicks "Yes" on a **radio button**, this div becomes visible via a `JavaScript` function. No problems there. When the user comes back to the page after closing it, however, or upon reload, the div is invisible again. I would like this div to remain visible after the user has selected "Yes." The value of that radio button is written to a database and is loaded when the page loads, so the "Yes" option will appear selected.

I have tried something like the following, but with no luck. I triggered this with a **body onload event**. (costShareYN1 is the radio button, costshare is the name of the div.)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show() {
  if (document.getElementById("costShareYN1").checked == true) {
      document.getElementById('costshare').style.visibility = "visible";
  }
}
</script>
```

I've also tried replacing `.checked == true` with `.value == "Yes"`, but to no avail. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How is it hidden initially?  If it's set to `display:none;` then doing `visibility = "visible"` won't help; you'll need to set `display:block`.

Comment: It is initially hidden with display:none; This solution worked. Much obliged.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery in you application then  just add following few additional lines:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function show() {
      if (document.getElementById("costShareYN1").checked == true) {
          document.getElementById('costshare').style.visibility = "visible";
      }
    }

    $(function(){
        if($('#costShareYN1').is(':checked'))
            $('#costshare').show();
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: helped us, thx. Maybe it's used [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kJt0vpx8Ca4&feature=youtube_gdata) , too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, you can use below code:

```
$('#costshare').show()
```